# Как в IntellJ IDEA или в Android Studio сделать так чтобы explorer был всегда раскрыт полностью?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm

Как в IntellJ IDEA или в Android Studio сделать так, чтобы explorer был всегда раскрыт полностью?

Слева вкладка есть Project. В Eclipse она была раскрыта всегда. То есть, дерево папок было открыто всегда.

Тут же, если закрыть Project и открыть то она становиться закрытой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Откройте это окно (оно называется Project Window): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
2. Найдите кнопку с шестерёнкой в верхней части, нажмите.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Отметьте галочкой пункт "Pinned Mode". Эта опция определяет, закрывается ли окно при переносе фокуса в редактор.

Comment: данная галочка стоит. Может в настрокайх нужно что то включить?

Так как если я запущу проект и Project будет закрыт то при открытии она будет закрытой и будет папка одна app.

И так каждый раз.

Comment: @xTIGRx а галочка на Docked mode?